# Quick evaluation of many functions at same point in Python

Tags: python, numpy

**Problem**: I need a very fast way in `Python3` to evaluate many (in the thousands) functions at the same argument. So in a sense, I kind of need the opposite of `NumPy's` Broadcasting which allows to quickly evaluate *one* function at *multiple* points.

**My solution**: At the moment I just store my functions in a list and then iterate over the list with a classic for loop to evaluate all functions individually. This however is much too slow.

Examples, ideas and links to packages very much welcome.

*Edit*: People have asked what the functions look like: 1. They are computational in nature. No I/O. 2. They only involve the usual algebraic operations like +, -, *, / and ** and also an indicator function. So no trigonometric functions or other special functions.

Comment: Have you tried with threads? And PyPy?

Comment: Can you post and example of your list?

Comment: have you tried a list comprehension? `[func(arg) for func in list_of_func]`

Comment: What factor of speedup do you need? The list comprehension by @Kasramvd should already be faster than a plain `for` loop. Cython can give you about 20% speedup without optimizations. PyPy is very good if you run each function multiple times as well (like, over 1000x).

Comment: @Kasramvd: Thanks, I just changed to list comprehension and then also had to change some code surrounding that part. The result is that everything is faster by a factor 3 according to `timeit`!

Comment: What kind of functions are you evaluating?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I have not used `PyPy` before. It says on their website the `Python3` version is still in beta mode, is it reliable?

Comment: Pypy for Python3 works fine in my tests. The major drawback is that they are somewhere at 3.2 or 3.3, while many nice goodies of Py3 come in 3.4. Depending on what you do, it might be worth offloading *some* parts of your program to pypy.

Comment: @TobiasR: I have edited my post to answer your question.

Comment: (1) It should be possible to vectorize the function and evaluate it at one vector of points then. I.e. instead of evaluating many different functions at one point, it may be possible to evaluate one vectorized function at many points. This should be much faster.
(2) After you did this, think about if you really need to know the exact value of the function at all those different points. You may be able to further speed up your program by approximating things. You may be able save some more time by interpolating your function by a simpler one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your functions are IO bound (meaning they spend most of their time waiting for some IO operation to complete), then using multiple threads may be a fair solution.

If your functions are CPU bound (meaning they spend most of their time doing actual computational work), then multiple threads will not help you, unless you are using a python implementation that does not have a [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

What you can do here, is use multiple python processes. The easiest solution being `multiprocessing` module. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import reduce

def a(x):
        return reduce(lambda memo, i: memo + i, x)
def b(x):
        return reduce(lambda memo, i: memo - i, x)
def c(x):
        return reduce(lambda memo, i: memo + i**2, x)

my_funcs = [a, b, c]

#create a process pool of 4 worker processes
pool = Pool(4)

async_results = []
for f in my_funcs:
        #seconds parameter to apply_async should be a tuple of parameters to pass to the function
        async_results.append(pool.apply_async(f, (range(1, 1000000),)))
results = list(map(lambda async_result: async_result.get(), async_results))
print(results)
```

This method allows you to utilize all your CPU power in parallel: just pick a pool size that matches the number of CPUs in your environment. The limitation of this approach is that all your functions must be [pickleable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate them using threading by running them in multiple threads, as long as they do not have resource conflicts.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Multithreading will not speed up anything. It's bound to one core. In fact, it'll likely be considerably *slower* as now the interpreter has to switch back and forth between threads. `multiprocessing` uses multiple cores.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It at least avoids running things in sequence, isn'it? Threading makes things to run in parallel. But as you said multiprocessing is best way to achieve it with best performance

Comment: Threading does **not** run things in parallel! It runs them concurrently. Basically, it means one task can be *paused*, another performed, then the initial one *resumed*. If there is a fixed list of operations to perform and they are not bound by external resources (I/O), then that pausing, switching and resuming may add considerable time. Multithreaded code may [run much slower on more processors](http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL/) due to this!

Comment: sorry for wrong terminology, i meant concurrent only. As you said, it slows down. Point taken.